# How to write tests in junit for methods that return void and implement runnable?

Tags: java, android, junit, junit3

I need to write junit tests for a method that implements the runnable and the whole logic of the code is within run() method.
for example:

```
public  class BookmarkController{
 public void addBookmark(final String url, final String title) {
       Runnable r = new Runnable() {
                   @Override
                   public void run() {
                                     //some logic

                                    };
}
}
```

can anybody tell me how to write tests for the method.

Comment: what do you want to test?

Comment: Also, I'm assuming that you left out the submission to a thread, because otherwise nothing's going to get executed (and the allocation of a `Runnable` might be optimized out).

Answer (score 0):

You run `addBookmark()` then I'm assuming you have a `getBookmarks()` method.  After you run the `addBookmark()`method, you check the `getBookmarks()` method to see if the bookmark you added with `addBookmark()` has been added.  If the thread that implements `Runnable` is expected to take some time, you do the test in a `RetriedAssert` which will retry the test over and over for a certain length of time.  Effectively waiting a certain length of time for a pass, if it still finds fails after the length of time, it's a fail.

```
new RetriedAssert(2000,100){
  public void run() throws Exception{
    assertTrue(yourClass.getBookMarks().contains(bookmark));
  }
}.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

In general , anonymous classes is equivalent to private methods, ie: implementation details are private, and ideally you should test the behaviour. It should be sufficient enough if your test  check if `BookMark` is added. Also you can think of using Mock framework (Setting expectations/ Verifying )